# Direct call without pressing green button flutter in ios build

Tags: android, flutter, dart, plugins

I m using call_number plugin for direct call in flutter but the problem is that this is only working for Android not for iOS how I can build this functionality in iOS build.

Answer (score 0):

Create your calling function as;

```
_call() async {
    if(numberToCall != null)
      await CallNumber().callNumber(numberToCall);
  }
```

example usage:

```
IconButton(onPressed: _call);
```

Comment: no this is not my problem this plugin callnumber only work for android not for ios .for android it is working fine